# Random Quotes script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

Trying to show a random quote on each rotation. I've got it working for the first instance, but then the list reverts back to the normal order. Here's what I have so far:

```
$(function (){
    var items = (Math.floor(Math.random() * ($('#quotes li').length)));
    $('#quotes li').hide().eq(items).show();

function next(){
    $('#quotes li:visible').delay(6000).fadeOut('slow',function(){
        $(this).appendTo('#quotes ul');
        $('#quotes li:first').fadeIn('slow',next);
});
}
next();
});
```

Cheers

Comment: Please include the HTML so I can test it out.

Comment: So what is your question? What specifically is not working or behaving different than you expect it to?

Comment: You put all the 'random' stuff before the function next is defined, then have next recall itself over and over. So really it'll pick a random quote on load, fade it out, then fade the first `<li>` it can find in over and over again.

Comment: Sorry my question isn't clear. I'm looking to show the quotes in a random order.

Comment: Replace   **Math.random()**  with **Math.random(timer())**  the former always replicates the same sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Your current algorithm (which doesn't randomize beyond the first displayed item) is as follows:

1. Select a random `<li>` tag.  Hide all the others and show this one.
2. After a delay, fadeOut the random one.
3. Move it to the end of the list.
4. Show the first one in the list.

So, you will select a random one to show first, but from then on you're just going to go in order.   There are a number of ways you could change the algorithm to be more random, but it depends upon what behavior you want (which you haven't specified).

For example, you could select a random element every time, but that might repeat elements before it shows others than haven't been seen yet.

Or, you could shuffle the `<li>` tags into random order and then show them one after another in the new random order.  When you get to the list, do another random shuffle, etc...

Here's a version of the code that does the random shuffle.  It puts all the elements in random order, then shows them one by one until it gets to the last one.  After showing the last one, it reshuffles the elements in random order again and then starts showing them one by one again, repeat over and over.  This guarantees random order and it guarantees that within one run, you don't repeat elements so all elements get shown the same number of times.  It is possible (due to random chance) that the same element might be shown twice in a row, but this can only happen if it's shown as the last element in one pass and then by random chance is also chosen as the first element in the next run.

Here's the code:

```
// efficient way to randomize an array of values
function fisherYatesShuffle(array ){
    var count = array.length,
      randomnumber,
      temp;
    while( count ){
        randomnumber = Math.random() * count-- | 0;
        temp = array[count];
        array[count] = array[randomnumber];
        array[randomnumber] = temp;
    }
}

$(function() {
    var index = 0;
    var quotesArray = $('#quotes li').get();
    var numItems = quotesArray.length;

    // randomize the elements
    function randomize() {
        fisherYatesShuffle(quotesArray);
    }

    // make sure the index is not past the end of the array
    // if so, randomize the elements again and reset the index
    function checkIndex() {
        if (index >= numItems) {
            randomize();
            index = 0;
        }
    }

    // process the next item with 6 second delay, then fadeOut, then fadeIn of next element
    function next() {
        $(quotesArray[index]).delay(6000).fadeOut('slow', function() {
            ++index;
            checkIndex();
            $(quotesArray[index]).fadeIn('slow', next);
        });

    }
    // randomize the items initially and show the first one after randomization
    randomize();
    $('#quotes li').hide();
    $(quotesArray[0]).show();
    next();
});
```

Working demo (with actual quotes): http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/gf5y46cp/

FYI, here's an article about the Fisher-Yates shuffle in Javascript: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. How would I go about the last scenario you mentioned?

Comment: @benmandv - I added a version of the code that shows them in continual random order.

Comment: Cheers for using the Fisher-Yates shuffle. (Although I think the implementation is missing?)

Comment: @NateBarbettini - added the missing code for the Fisher-Yates Shuffle.  Forgot to paste it in.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to tackle the problem, which I think is much cleaner:

```
// An array of possible quotes
var quotes = [
    'Genius is one percent inspiration, ninety-nine percent perspiration. (Thomas Edison)', 
    'The real problem is not whether machines think but whether men do. (B.F. Skinner)',
    'There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things. (Phil Karlton)',
    'If today were the last day of your life, would you want to do what you are about to do today? (Steve Jobs)'];
var currentQuote = 0;

function nextQuote(showImmediately) {
    // We can use a promise to make sure that we don't switch the
    // quote out until the text is hidden
    var hidden = $.Deferred();

    if (!showImmediately)
        $('#quotes').fadeOut('slow', function() { hidden.resolve(); });
    else
        hidden.resolve();

    // Once the promise is resolved, go ahead and modify the DOM
    hidden.promise().done(function() {

        // Get a quote that's not the current one
        // (we may need to try a few times if it's a small array
        var randomIndex = currentQuote;
        while (randomIndex == currentQuote) {
            randomIndex = (Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length));
        }

        // Now switch it out and fade back in        
        $('#quotes').html(quotes[randomIndex]);
        $('#quotes').fadeIn('slow');
        currentQuote = randomIndex;
    });
}

nextQuote(true);
setInterval(function() { nextQuote(false); }, 6000);
```

Working fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jd6tyqe8/)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following script, it shows random quote from your quotes array.

```js
(function() {
  var arrayQ = [{
    quote: "The material world is a dangerous place to be in. It's dangerous because there is a temptation of illusory energy; there is danger at every step.",
    source: "HH GOPAL KRISHNA GOSWAMI",
    citation: "ISKCON DESIRE TREE",
    year: 2016
  }, {
    quote: "If you carry out the order of your spiritual master then the Lord will be so pleased that He will come to see you.",
    source: "HH GOPAL KRISHNA GOSWAMI",
    citation: "ISKCON DESIRE TREE",
    year: 2013
  }, {
    quote: "Our vaccination is chanting the names of Krishna, Hearing the Bhagavad-gita and Srimad Bhagavatam, and thinking of Krishna all the time.",
    source: "HH GOPAL KRISHNA GOSWAMI",
    citation: "ISKCON DESIRE TREE",
    year: 2003
  }, {
    quote: "Vairagya means that when the opportunity for sense gratification is there, I voluntarily abstain from it.",
    source: "HH GOPAL KRISHNA GOSWAMI",
    citation: "ISKCON DESIRE TREE",
    year: 2006
  }, {
    quote: "Our quota is not sixteen rounds, but attentive sixteen rounds.",
    source: "HH GOPAL KRISHNA GOSWAMI",
    citation: "ISKCON DESIRE TREE",
    year: 2009
  }, {
    quote: "Guru is pleased when he sees that the disciple is showing the symptoms of Shudh Bhakti.",
    source: "HH GOPAL KRISHNA GOSWAMI",
    citation: "ISKCON DESIRE TREE",
    year: 2010
  }, {
    quote: "Devotional service is so simple, but devotees because of their material inclinations make it complicated.",
    source: "HH GOPAL KRISHNA GOSWAMI",
    citation: "ISKCON DESIRE TREE",
    year: 2011
  }, {
    quote: "Whatever we give to Krishna that will be remembered eternally, that will be appreciated eternally.",
    source: "HH GOPAL KRISHNA GOSWAMI"
  }, ];

  var randomQuotes = function() {
    var getRandomInt = function(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
      },
      index = getRandomInt(0, arrayQ.length),
      quote = arrayQ[index],
      quoteElm = document.getElementById('quote');
    if (quote) {
      quoteElm.innerHTML = quote.quote;
      arrayQ.splice(index, 1); // remove quote from array
    }
  };
  setInterval(function() {
    randomQuotes()
  }, 1500);
})();
```

```css
#quote {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="quote"></div>
```